# Angular encapsulation param

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

When I generated a new component with Angular CLI I always got a new component with params:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test1',
  templateUrl: './test1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test1.component.css']
})
```

But now something goes wrong. When I use ng g c [name] I get one more additional param, which I have to import into component, I mean encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test1',
  templateUrl: './test1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test1.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

I was trying to reinstall node/angular cli and etc. No result. What do I have to do to create a new components without parameter "encapsulation"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you eventually get a solution to work or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mtpults says, PR was pushed and merged for https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8374 that solves this issue. Currently it is only on master so the above will be a stopgap till the do a minor release. After the release if you read the PR everything will be like it was previously.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of the cli you are using there may be an option that you have set in your config. See if you have the following in your `.angular-cli.json`

```
"component": {
   "viewEncapsulation": "None"
},
```

That being said there is a defect in `1.5.0` of the CLI that I found when testing this issue. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8383

Comment: I was trying to add this into my project .angular-cli.json - and there is no any result

Comment: It goes within the defaults block. Also there is a defect per my link too.

Answer (score 0):

ViewEncapsulation defaults to `Emulated` for v2, v4, and v5 of Angular.  So if you just remove `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`, which is now added to the generated component in v1.5 of the Angular CLI, or change it to `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` you'll be using the default.

This can be removed automatically during component generation using the Angular CLI by adding the component `ViewEncapsulation` defaults to the `angular.cli.json` see [wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli) for all available keys.

```
"defaults": {
  "styleExt": "scss",
  "component": {
    "viewEncapsulation": "Emulated"
  }
}
```

There are three enumerated types of `ViewEncapsulation` to choose from: `Emulated`, `Native`, and `None` if you're not familiar with `ViewEncapsulation` see [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation).  If you're not familiar with `ViewEncapsulation` and how it relates to the shadow DOM this is a good [article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html).

If you choose to do this manually for each component you'll need to import `ViewEncapsulation`, which is at the time of writing is missing from the generated component.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

**UPDATE**

A PR was pushed and merged for https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8374 that solves this issue.  Currently it is only on master so the above will be a stopgap till the do a minor release.  After the release if you read the PR everything will be like it was previously.